# Angular Firebase "Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.UID.email' "

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new firebase database, I try to update UID to Realtime Database when signup, but got an error like this

> Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.UID.email'

auth.service.ts

```
import ...
...
export class AuthService { 
...

 async emailSignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      const user = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log('user ', user);
      this.authState = user;
      console.log('authState ', this.authState);
      this.updateUserData();
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
  }

 get currentUserId(): string {
    console.log('currentId ', this.authenticated, ' ', this.authState.user.uid);
    return this.authenticated ? this.authState.user.uid : '';
  }

 private updateUserData(): void {
    const path = `users/${this.currentUserId}`; // Endpoint on firebase
    const userRef: AngularFireObject<any> = this.db.object(path);
    const data = {
      email: this.authState.email,
      name: this.authState.displayName
    };
    userRef.update(data)
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

}
```

Console
[image]

Can somebody help me, please?
please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `this.authState.email` is undefined.  It's not valid to pass an undefined value to Realtime Database.  You should check that before using it this way.

I'm seeing that you assigned `this.authState` from `user` in your constructor.  Your logged `user` in the console, and it doesn't have a property called `email`, so this error does not surprise me at all.  But it does have a property also called `user`.  So, perhaps you meant `this.authState.user.email` instead.